# Monitoring an uninvited guest on my WLAN?

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, monitoring, intrusion

At home I configured a common, residential, consumer-grade wireless
network. It is build from a Broadcom router connecting a few personal devices (i.e. my laptop & smartphone) to the Internet.

My WLAN is not public and secured through WPA2.

Recently I discovered an unfamiliar host on my private WLAN.

Can I monitor and investigate that particular hosts traffic to try and identify who it is, or what they're doing?

How may I proceed against what looks like an uninvited scrounger?

Comment: This other question was about protecting other users, this one is about analyzing what a potential enemy is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have control of the network equipment then yes you can log and monitor their actions.

**Full packet capture:** Ideally you want full-packet capture of all traffic at key ingress/egress points for each segment. You asked for the best way to do this and this would give you the most data about traffic on your network. Even if you can only capture the traffic at one point that you know this unfamiliar host is using to connect to the Internet you will learn a lot.

**NetFlow:** If full-packet capture is not an option you may be able to enable NetFlow of some form on the devices and see the connections made by this unfamiliar host. This won't be as comprehensive as full packet capture but it will give you a ton of great information.

**Firewall Rules or access-control-lists used to log:** You may be able to enable logging-only firewall rules on the devices which this unfamiliar host is communicating through. Depending on the type of device used the level of logging information will vary. Some device can do packet captures which would be great if that's an option.

**Look at the DNS cache** (or record DNS queries) made by the unfamiliar host if he/she is using your DNS. You may need to enable WireShark/tshark on the DNS server but at least it will give you more information about the user, the type of software they are running, and possibly company affiliations.

**Proxy or webfilter logs:** If your network happens to have any kind webproxy to protect client end-points from surfing to potentially dangerous sites you could look at these logs. Given you are asking the question you are asking I suspect you don't have this.

**Vulnerability Scanning Logs:** Does your network get regular vulnerability scans ? If so see what data it recorded about this host.

**Internal web server logs:** Do you think this device may have accessed an internal website ? If so see if you can get User-Agent information from the web server log relating to this host. This may help you identify the device and if it's a mobile device you can get a lot of information about it **sometimes including the devices firmware version**.

Those are the places to start looking for passive analysis. Obviously more can be done if you are allowed to actively probe the device but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: I'm happy to probe it. I mean, it's my network, who's permission do i need?

Comment: In that case nmap with verbose options is your friend. B-)

Comment: That's actually how I discovered it in the first place. It's generating a lot of traffic, I just want to know what that traffic is, basically.